# How to generate a lambda at runtime passing a property name as string?

Tags: c#, linq, runtime, expression

I have a list of `PolicyTran` objects:

```
List<PolicyTran> AllTransactions;
```

I need to run a query filtering by a property, e.g:

```
var insureds = AllTransactions.Select(x => x.Insured).ToList();
```

That works fine, but I need to pass the `x.Insured` property at runtime since that property could take different values.

I tried doing:

```
ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof (PolicyTran),"x");
MemberExpression body = Expression.Property(x, propertyName);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body,x).Compile();
var result = AllTransactions.Select(lambda).ToList();
```

In this case `propertyName` contains "Insured" or any other `PolicyTran` property.
But I get a compilation error saying that "The type arguments cannot be inferred by the ussage..."

I also tried, but no luck:

```
ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof (PolicyTran),"x");
var result = AllTransactions.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<PolicyTran, bool>>(x).Compile()).ToList();
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first attempt is closer to the solution. You just need to call the generic version of `Lambda`:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<PolicyTran, object>>(body, x).Compile();
```

in order to get a `Func<PolicyTran, object>` delegate.

Otherwise the labda will return a simple `System.Delegate` from which the LINQ `.Select` will be unable to infer the types.

Comment: That worked perfect, thanks ! I was close... Will accept your answer when it lets me